# Perform action on web page and store result in php

Tags: php, browser, curl, httprequest

cURL can request a URL and store the requested page...but I'm wondering...can PHP actually perform an action on a web page (like fill out and submit a form) and store information about the requested page?

Comment: Yes. There's not much else I can say, as you haven't given us any more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cURL to perform POST, HEAD, PUT, DELETE, and any other HTTP operation you can imagine. This simulates the submission of most forms online. When you use cURL's ability to use a cookie file, and fake a user agent, you can fake a browser.

Check out [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) on `curl_setopt` specifically the parts on CURLOPT_POST, CURLOPT_PUT, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, and CURLOPT_USERAGENT

You can also check information about the requested page through `curl_getinfo($handle)`

Answer (score 1):

A simple login example would involve say a username and a password.

```
$ch = curl_init();

$data = array('username' => 'xyz', 'password' => 'abc');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://website.com/login.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'close_cookies.txt');

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The two cookie lines are meant to store the cookies on your server so they can be read at anytime. At after the `curl_exec($ch)` line you remain logged into the website and could create more POST or GET requests without having to log back in.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer...just one question..So this fills fields 'username' and 'password'. Is this for fields with id='username' .. or name='username'...how is it identifying what fields to fill?

Comment: It would be for `name="username"`

Comment: When I use curl_getinfo on this...I'm getting "http://website.com/login.php" as the URL..not the requested page's URL.